# Resize fotoroma library popup

Tags: jquery, magento, gallery, magento2, fotorama

In Magento 2 default gallery popup is showing in full width and height.
But I need to resize it with js. Is it possible from library end or any customisation.

Comment: Have you checked view.xml

Comment: yes I have already putted it in my theme and checked for popup width and height parameter which isn't available there.

Comment: Then you need some css help to reduce that

Comment: it would be more appropriate to make it possible in javascript

Comment: @SintuRoy did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the the file app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/etc/view.xml

We can see a variable named 
Inside that variable we have option to enable/disable full screen mode and lot of other customizations also.

```
<var name="allowfullscreen">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
```

Comment: This is only for enable or disable the fullscreen , but I need to make popup of my custom size for which there isn't any other option available in view.xml

Comment: For the popup customization, we need to edit the css file of the fotorama plugin.